# r- ggplot2: polar line plot with 2 lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, polygon

Using `ggplot2`, I am trying to graph two treatments in a polar line graph. I'm able to graph the points for both treatments and get a line for the first treatment that I input, but the line that I want to connect the second subset is just overlaying over the second.

```
  category highest lowest
  1        A      71     23
  2        B      81     38
  3        C      77     22
  4        D      83     56
  5        E      84     32
  6        F      82     55
  7        G      73     26
```

So far, my code looks like this

```
p1<-ggplot(data=d,aes(x=factor(category),y=highest,group=1)) + 
ylim(0,NA) +
geom_point(color='purple',stat='identity')+
geom_polygon(color='purple',fill=NA)+
coord_polar(start =-pi* 1/7)

p1

p1 + 
geom_point(aes(x=factor(category),y=lowest),color='green',stat='identity')+
geom_polygon(color='green',fill=NA)+
coord_polar(start =-pi* 1/7)
```

and its looking like this

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr0Sh.png)

Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Is this kind of what you were going for (spider plots)? http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/143-spider-chart-with-saveral-individuals/

Answer (score 1):

You are still using the overall y aesthetic ("highest") in the second `geom_polygon` call.  To plot a different column, you'll need to define it in `aes` within the layer.

```
geom_polygon(aes(y = lowest), color='green',fill=NA)
```

The more standard way to do such a plot, though, is to get your dataset into a long format, where you grouping variable (highest and lowest) is a variable and all your y values are in a single column for plotting.

```
library(reshape2)
d2 = melt(d, id.var = "category")
```

Once you have that you can map `color` to the grouping variable.  You set colors to specific values using `scale_color_manual`.  You get a legend by default (which might be a good thing), but you an suppress it using `guide = "none"`.

```
ggplot(data=d2, aes(x=factor(category), y=value, group = variable, color = variable)) + 
    ylim(0,NA) +
    geom_point(, stat='identity') +
    geom_polygon(fill=NA)+
    coord_polar(start =-pi* 1/7) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "green"), guide = "none")
```

Both approaches give the same plot in the end:
[image]